# In Bottom Navigation Bar, how to I remove the Active Item Indicator?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

[Looks like this currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW0bf.png)

I want to remove this purple highlight, but I am not able to find an option for the same.

I tried to find the documentation. I found an option to change the color, but not for turning it off. I also searched tutorials on youtube, but was not able to find any useful one.

Comment: Can you post your code for bottom bar?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting the color of the ActiveItemIndicator to a transparent color